# I am not able to access TextEditingController using bloc in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, text, bloc

How to access TextEditingController(); using bloc . here my code :-
after i use

**`BlocProvider.of<UsernameupdateCubit>(context).nameUpdate(userUpdateController.text)`;**

I got an error which is
BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a UsernameupdateCubit.

Please check :
**I use**

```
final userUpdateController = TextEditingController();
```

**then**

```
TextFormField(
          controller: userUpdateController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: "Full Name",
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            prefixIcon: Icon(FeatherIcons.user, size: 24),
          ),
        ),
```

after that use a button to save/sent/access anywhere or display in list view :
**button is :**

```
Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd,
          child: ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              elevation: 1,
              primary: Color(0xff34495e),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              // BlocProvider.of<UsernameupdateCubit>(context).nameUpdate();
              // BlocProvider.of<WeatherBloc>(context)
              BlocProvider.of<UsernameupdateCubit>(context)
                  .nameUpdate(userUpdateController.text);
            },
            child: Text(
              "Continue",
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

My Cubit :

```
class UsernameupdateCubit extends Cubit<UsernameupdateState> {
  UsernameupdateCubit() : super(UsernameupdateState(userUpdateName: ''));

  void nameUpdate(userUpdateController) =>
      emit(UsernameupdateState(userUpdateName: userUpdateController.text));
}
```

and state is :

```
    class UsernameupdateState {
  String userUpdateName;
  UsernameupdateState({
    required this.userUpdateName,
  });
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with TextEditingController. Where is your UsernameupdateCubit located? Do you have a BlocProvider somewhere that instantiates it?

Comment: yes, you are right. I solved this issue .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all are same but I include BlocProvider in :
using multibloc:

```dart
    BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => UsernameupdateCubit(),
    ),
```

after that I changed my cubit  :

```dart
    void nameUpdate(userUpdateController) =>
      emit(UsernameupdateState(userUpdateName: userUpdateController));
```

and yes that's it .
thank you – @nvoigt #nvoigt